# Broker that supports both ISA accounts and API access?

Tags: api, stocks, stock

I'm looking for a stockbroker but can't seem to find one that 'ticks all the right boxes' - can anyone help please?!

The *essential* requirements are:

- Supports Shares ISA accounts
- Access to ETFs on the LSE, especially iShares
- Real-time price info/trading (with as low latency as possible)
- Low fees/charges (preferably with a heavy discount for say 10+ trades per week)
- Available to individuals, not just institutions

Execution-only is fine, don't need anything fancy. The ISA requirement probably restricts it to UK brokers I guess. There are loads of brokers that do all of the above, so then it comes down to my key *additional* requirement:

- API access, e.g. FIX (for automated/algorithmic trading)

But I can't find any brokers that have both ISA support and API access. I guess it mustn't be a common requirement for individual investors in the UK but it seems commonly available from US brokers. I can probably live without API access if I really have to. (As long as there's a web interface, which they all seem to do nowadays. And I have no requirement for desktop/mobile trading platform software.)

My '*would really like but can be flexible on*' requirements are:

- Existing (open source/cheap) connector for Marketcetera or similar
- Real-time level 2 price info at a reasonable price
- DMA (Direct Market Access) on the LSE at a reasonable price (preferably without a massive 'professional client' process to have to go through)

Then the optional/'nice to have's are:

- Demo/'monopoly money' account for testing
- Ultra low latency pricing/trades
- Can switch into CFDs/spreadbetting
- Also supports SIPPs

So, does anyone know of any brokers that meet some/all these requirements?

The cheapest ones I've found that meet my essential requirements are x-o.co.uk and hl.co.uk, both currently charging £5.95. There's also share.com whose Premium account might be useful in the future but rather pricey up front - £3000 per year for unlimited trades with no other major charges. E*TRADE might have done the job but they're no longer trading in the UK. Interactive Brokers seems to be the only choice for API access in the UK (?) but they don't support ISAs. (They've said "After reviewing this we have decided not to support ISA's at this time." so it won't happen anytime soon.) There are some nice-looking platforms like Marketcetera/JBookTrader/tradelink/ActiveQuant - but if they can't connect to a broker that does ISAs they're skuppered for my purposes.

And some additional questions while I'm thinking:

1. Anyone know how much latency there actually is on a normal UK retail broker's web interface's "real-time" prices/trades?
2. Are stock prices pretty much the same across different brokers? I read in a review somewhere that one broker didn't offer as good a stock prices as others?! Is this down to the RSPs they use maybe?
3. Is it even possible to get DMA on the LSE at a reasonable price without a massive 'professional client' process to have to go through?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, the website for programming questions! Have you got a programming question? :-)

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's not even one question. If you are a professional (not an amateur) you might get an answer on quantexchange.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that IG brokers may have both [ISA](http://www.ig.com/uk/stocks-and-shares-isa)s and and an [API](http://labs.ig.com)... Can't seem to find any others.

Comment: At IG.com you can only trade via API using CFD or Spread Betting account - you will NOT be able to trade stocks using neither Stock Trading nor ISA accounts. Moreover while their Spread Betting account offers many useful tools and feature (stops, limits, trailing stops) their stock trading accounts are very limited - no trailing stops and normal stop/limit orders expire at the market closing time, which means you have to watch the market yourself and place new orders everyday which may be bothersome or even problematic if trading is not your full time occupation.

Comment: The api for the stocks and shares ISA is most useful as a filter to see if IG offer a market for that particular instrument. I would suggest obtaining market data from bloomberg or some other source